# Add and read later custom variables in tinyMCE.init

Tags: php, javascript, tinymce

I added this:

```
        article_id: <?php echo $edit ?>
});
```

just in the end of tinyMCE.init. I would like to get the article id in simpleimage plugin and make an AJAX query to load a list of images. How can I read article_id variable? I get undefined.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `tinymce.get('my_editor_id').settings.article_id`